# solving equation symbolically for a given variable in Maxima

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving, nonlinear-system, maxima-software

I can solve an equation using Maxima by using the commands below.

```
kill(all);
A:A; phase:phase; solve(A*cos(2*pi*f*t+phase)=y,phase);
```

And it gives me the correct answer.

```
phase=acos(y/A)-2*f*pi*t
```

$$[\text{phase}=\arccos\frac y A -2 f \pi t ]$$

But when I try and solve for just the top portion of an equation the `x(n+1)` portion. Here's the equation.

$$x_{n+1}=\sin(ay_n)+c\cos(ax_n)$$
$$y_{n+1}=\sin(bx_n)+d\cos(by_n)$$

See website [Clifford Attractor](https://fronkonstin.com/2017/11/07/drawing-10-million-points-with-ggplot-clifford-attractors/).

It's not what I expected. The equation I use is below:

```
kill(all);
x:x; a:a; c:c; n:n; solve(sin(a*y(n))+c*cos(a*x(n))=x*(n+1),x);
```

What I get is :

```
x=(sin(a*y(n))+c*cos(a*x(n)))/(n+1)
```

$$[x = \frac{ \sin(a y(n))+c \cos (ax(n))}{n+1}]$$

I expected it to be something like:

```
x[n] = sin(a*y[n-1])+c*cos(a*x[n-1]);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using wxMaxima 18.02.0 in ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command ["`kill (all)` unbinds all items on all infolists"](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_singlepage.html#IDX22).

The assignements `x:x; a:a;...` look rather useless to me and I would skip them. What is the purpose?

Maybe you want to do `x:'x;` and "clear" the value of `x`this way. But `kill(all)` already did this.

Maxima does what you tell it to do. I think you actually want to calculate

```
solve(sin(a*y(n))+c*cos(a*x(n))=x(n+1), x(n+1))
```

If you do this then Maxima returns

```
[x(n+1) = sin(a*y(n))+c*cos(a*x(n))]
```

Note that `x(n)` is a function call and `x[n]` is accessing an array or list element.